# m2eclipse and tomcat

Tags: tomcat, m2eclipse

I started to use m2eclipse. After install, i download some archetype, maven install, package, clean works ggreat. Now i wanted to start my application and make it show in my browser. My first problem was I can't do Run as-> run on server. All my non-maven project can be run on server. 
My second try: run as-> run configuration, then select tomcat. Tomcat started, configured and... nothing. It doeasnt show my site. I input in my browser manually: http://localhost:8080/(my project name) and I got :

> The requested resource (/RestFinderMaven/index.jsp) is not available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to deploy your webapp via the WTP server tools, you need to install m2e-wtp. for more informations, please take a look at http://community.jboss.org/en/tools/blog/2011/06/23/m2eclipse-wtp-0130-new-noteworthy